# Nested If Statement Using Case Statement in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I inherited a spreadsheet from a co-worker who used a nested If statement as shown below:

```
  =IF(AND([@[Pred Type]]="PR_FS",[@[ST Finish]]="A"),
      0,
      IF(AND([@[Pred Type]]="PR_SS", OR([@[ACT_START_DATE]]<>0,[@[ST Start]]="A")),
         0,
         IF(AND([@[Pred Type]]="PR_SF",OR([@[ACT_START_DATE]]<>0,[@[ST Start]]="A")),
            0,
            IF(AND([@[Pred Type]]="PR_FF",[@[STFinish]]="A"),0,1)
           )
        )
     )
```

I know I can write a CASE statement that would mimic this but can't figure out the syntax for it. I tried:

```
,CASE   WHEN #Preds.Pred_Type = 'PR_FS' and #Tbl_Sched_Act.Expected_Finish = 'A' THEN 0 
    WHEN #Preds.Pred_Type = 'PR_SS' OR ACT_START_DATE IS NOT NULL OR Start_RAW IS NOT NULL THEN 0
    WHEN #Preds.Pred_Type = 'PR_SF'OR ACT_START_DATE IS NOT NULL OR Start_RAW IS NOT NULL THEN 0
    WHEN #Preds.Pred_Type = 'PR_FF' and #Tbl_Sched_Act.Expected_Finish = 'A' THEN 0 
    ELSE 1
    END as PRED_MET
```

However, the CASE statement does not evaluate any of the items to be equal to 1. They all evaluate to 0 which isn't correct.

Does anyone have any idea on how I could write my CASE statement correctly?

Comment: Please post table DDL, sample data, and expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group the `OR` inside parenthesis `()` to force operator precedence.

```
CASE   
    WHEN #Preds.Pred_Type = 'PR_FS' and #Tbl_Sched_Act.Expected_Finish = 'A' 
    THEN 0 
    WHEN #Preds.Pred_Type = 'PR_SS' 
     AND (ACT_START_DATE <> 0 OR Start_RAW <> 0) 
    THEN 0
    WHEN #Preds.Pred_Type = 'PR_SF'
     AND (ACT_START_DATE <> 0 OR Start_RAW <> 0)
    THEN 0
    WHEN #Preds.Pred_Type = 'PR_FF' and #Tbl_Sched_Act.Expected_Finish = 'A' 
    THEN 0           
    ELSE 1
END as PRED_MET
```

***NOTE:***: If a number is `<> 0` then also is `NOT NULL` [**DEMO**](http://rextester.com/BZBK85560)

But that can also be simplify to:

```
CASE   
    WHEN #Tbl_Sched_Act.Expected_Finish = 'A' 
     AND #Preds.Pred_Type  IN ('PR_FS', 'PR_FF')
    THEN 0 
    WHEN (ACT_START_DATE <> 0 OR Start_RAW <> 0) 
     AND (#Preds.Pred_Type IN ('PR_SS','PR_SF')
    THEN 0
    ELSE 1
END as PRED_MET
```

Comment: That worked. It was the parenthesis that I couldn't figure out. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Took you 5 month to get it work? remember mark the answer as correct using the green tick

Comment: I don't see a green tick mark. I honestly had forgotten about this until I got a notification just yesterday. Weird.